# How to get a Big-θ by this function?

Tags: python

```
def abc(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return 1
    return abc(N-1) + abc(N-2)
```

I'm trying to learn Python right now but I'm having a bit of trouble here. I'd like to determine this function by Big-θ. How would I approach this? Thanks!

Comment: yes big-O would help me also. Could you tell me why big-θ doesn't make sense please? Thanks!

Comment: [Fibonacci series recursion time complexity](https://www.google.com/search?q=fibonacci+series+recursion+time+complexity&oq=fi&aqs=edge.0.69i59j69i57j0i67l4j69i60l2j69i61.3436j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)